# Serialization vs. Byte Code Translation

Tags: java, xml, json, serialization, bytecode

I'm a beginner with programming, and I was just wondering if there is a difference between the process of serialization and the process of converting to and from byte code (intermediate language).

I found this on javacodegeeks.com:

> Serialization is usually used When the need arises to send your data
>   over network or stored in files. By data I mean objects and not text.
>   Now the problem is your Network infrastructure and your Hard disk are
>   hardware components that understand bits and bytes but not Java
>   objects. Serialization is the translation of your Java object’s
>   values/states to bytes to send it over network or save it. --> *On
>   other hand, Deserialization is conversion of byte code to
>   corresponding java objects.* <--

From my understanding of this paragraph, serialization may be the process by which java converts its programs to byte code for the ability to transport to different computer environments and still function correctly.

Am I correct in thinking this?

Answer (score 10):

> From my understanding of this paragraph, serialization may be the process by which java converts its programs to byte code for the ability to transport to different computer environments and still function correctly. Am I correct in thinking this?

No, compiling with javac creates the byte code that runs on the JVM. VMs (such as the JVM) INTERPRET the bytecode and use some clever and complicated just-in-time compilation (which IS machine/platform-dependent) to give you the final product. See bytecode is just a bunch of [instructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings) that the JVM interprets. Each bytecode opcode is one byte in length, hence the name bytecode.

Serialization on the other hand, converts the state of a Java object into a stream of bytes. These bytes are not instructions like bytecode. Primary purpose of Java Serialization is to write an object into a stream, so that it can be transported through a network and that object can be rebuilt again. When there are two different parties involved, you need a protocol to rebuild the exact same object again. Java serialization API just provides you that. Other ways you can leverage the feature of serialization is, you can use it to perform a deep copy.

> Now the problem is your Network infrastructure and your Hard disk are hardware components that understand bits and bytes but not Java objects. Serialization is the translation of your Java object’s values/states to bytes to send it over network or save it. --> On other hand, Deserialization is conversion of byte code to corresponding java objects.

See you can't just pass a java object to the link layer of the network and expect it to be able to send. Networks send bits and bytes across the physical medium. So serializable lets you encode an object in a standard way to binary, pass it across the network, and then decode it at the receiving end back to the object in the exact state the object was in on the sending side

Comment: to expand on this, byte code is one step in the process of executing a java program [as shown here](http://img.viralpatel.net/2008/12/java-program-execution.png). Serialization is a process used in certain situations by many programming languages (it may go by different names) to, as sunrize explained, convert an object into bytes for storage/transportation. one common use of serialization is file writing.