# Byte Code vs Stream of bytes(Serialization)

Tags: java, serialization

I have a question regarding byte code and serialization.

bytecode - every java class is converted to bytecode for compilation and stored on the memory (disk) as stream of bytes / bytecode.

Serialization - Serialization is the process of saving an object's state to a sequence of bytes.

can't this bytecode itself be used to send through network ?

So what is the exact difference between the two ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has already been asked / answered : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025851/serialization-vs-byte-code-translation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concepts are completely unrelated.

> every java class is converted to bytecode for compilation

No, it isn't converted *for* compilation. [Bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode) is the *result* of compilation. It is, well, code which is run by a virtual machine (JVM in Java's case) like machine code is run directly by the CPU. It is binary (a sequence of bytes instead of characters) simply because it's a more compact representation. It doesn't contain state of any objects (except for constants).

Serialization stores the state of an object (default Java serialization is binary, but other libraries/languages can use text). The serialized object doesn't contain bytecode: you can't run it or in JVM.

Answer (score 2):

- **Serialization** - Serialization is the process of saving an object's
  state to a sequence of bytes This bytecode can be sent through
  network and after be deserialized it will be loaded into another jvm
  as normal object
- **Compilation** - Compilation is the process of creating bytecode from
  class java, then be loaded into local jvm. If you want to use objects
  in other jvm, then you have to implement Serializable interface

Answer (score 1):

Yes, bytecode（java class file）can be used to send through network, but by sending a bytecode, you transferred a java class not a java object.

Serialization is used to save or transfer object.